# Expo React Native useAuthRequest Popup covers keyboard

Tags: react-native, facebook-authentication, expo

Why does the keyboard get covered by the popup?
[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AcC3.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. For the sake of the community, you shouldn't use a link to a screenshot that may be unusable in the future.
Either paste the image directly inside your question, or describe what happens.

Good luck to you!